# Time issue in calendar entries in google apps

Tags: c#

I am migrating the Calendar entries with recurrence from outlook to google apps.But  the start time and the end time of the same recurrence entry in google apps is not coming correctly.The time zone of google apps account is set as (GMT+00.00)GMT(no daylight saving).
Please help.

Regards
Sanchaita chakraborty

Comment: Would need to see at least _some_ code to even begin to help with this

Comment: can you please show some example of what format of date are you getting and what is expacted... In which format and time zone do you want your Date like IST.. please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from your question what you are asking..
But As i checked in google documentation a time format like this is used in API `2010-03-29T13:12:38.861Z`.

So u can easily convert it to C# datetime object by using [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) method. however it returns the date in your current culture timezone. If you want the time zone of the Actual date you can use [DateTimeTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) and provide the CultureInfo.